# Add angular binding to node added by jquery

Tags: jquery, angularjs, data-binding

Is it possible to bind a model to an html node which is added by jQuery? I tried:

```
 $('mydiv').append('<input ng-model="myValue" type ="text" );
```

what does not work. Model is not binded.

Comment: I'd rather advise you to drop jQuery manipulation with Angularjs, it's MVC the View should be driven by Controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) the new element

```
//assuming $scope refer to the scope to which it has to be binded
var $el = $('<input ng-model="myValue" type ="text" />').appendTo('mydiv')
$compile($el)($scope);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6LFJV/1/)